# Scope of a let variable

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and am trying to pull geolocation data (longitude/latitude) from the browser. I am trying to understand the scope of the let variables lat and long.

When printed to the console, I receive the following output:

3: undefined

2: undefined

1: 40.112

Why do I receive undefined in the console at all?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let lat;
  let long;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      long = position.coords.longitude;

      console.log('1: ' + lat)
    })
    console.log('2: ' + lat)
  }
  console.log('3: ' + lat)
})
```

Comment: You should receive 2: undefined, 3: undefined, 1: 40.112.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous: it'll run in the background while the code afterwards keeps running, then it'll call the callback function once it finishes. So, you queue up the `getCurrentPosition`, then before it's finished, you log `2: lat` and `3: lat`, which are both undefined due to not being set yet.

Then, once you finally get the position, the function is called and `1: lat` is logged, where the value is finally set.